# What kind of global variable is bad practice in java?

Tags: java, global

For many of my java projects, I use database extensively, what I usually do is to have a `property.xml` file to hold all my strings and settings.

And then I would have a class `CNST` to hold all the static constants corresponding to those in the xml file.

Those constants are initialized by the xml file once when the program starts, and used as globals anywhere later on in the program.

However, after reading many articles these days, it seems that using globals at all is not such a good practice. So please can anyone may indicate a good practice fo this situation? Thanks.

Comment: use a resource file instead... see `Properties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general global variables should be avoided when it is possible => this however is not an issue if they are constants. For cases like this one when you (presumably) initialize this global-settings wrapper object at the beginning and nothing is changed afterwards, there are these options:

- Having constants (`public static final`) which are initialized in `static` block
- Having the variables `private static final` initialized in `static` block  and exposed via getters
- Creating a singleton and having the variables `private final` exposed via getters

The 2nd and 3rd point has advantage over the 1st that in getter methods you have encapsulated the values of variables and can change/insert code which  manipulates the value to be returned to calling method without effecting the (calling) code dependent on it.

Comment: this is great, thanks. However, as for the 2nd and 3rd option, which may be better? I have detailed my question in [What is the better way of publishing global constants in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169614/what-is-the-better-way-of-publishing-global-constants-in-java), Please have a look, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using global variables means they are visible to many classes who can manipulate the data then.

So you will have to take care of your data is it is widely visible.

And if you are using multithreading then you are in trouble as anybody can modify that data, so lots of scope for data getting corrupted.

As a matter of practice i follow following points:

1. Keep variable visiblity minimal, private if possible.
2. Make it immutable wherever possible.

Comment: So does it mean as long as my global variable are constants, they are OK?

Comment: Yup, constants can be global. In fact if you are having final static variable to be used as constants, its beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

You can freely use public static constants or variables. If you use non-static variables then good practice is to use Getters and Setters. If your class conatains only static constants then you can also use private constructor to restrict creating instances of this class.

```
public class Global {

    public static final int A;
    public static final int B;

    private Global() {} // use only when you have only static fields and methods

    static {
        A = 1;
        B = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did. But all those articles about `global=terrible` freaks me out a little.

Comment: This is normal and useful practice in Java. You can use these constructions and this is not "terrible" practice. Maybe in articles was writed about public non-static and non-const fields?

Comment: Some did say if it is not mutable it `may be OK`, but that's not nearly as strong as the main tone of the article which made me wonder in the first place. Anyway, as long as I am sure that this is good practice, it's OK. I will look into the disadvantages of mutable globals a bit more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `public static` variable instead of Global variable that would be a better idea.

Check out this [link](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

One other approach is to create a class that follows the `singleton` pattern, so there can only be one instance of the class and keep the variable in the singleton class and access it with `get` and `set` methods.

**Edit1:-**

Go for the old style in case of declaring the constants. Something like this:-

```
(public/private) static final TYPE NAME = VALUE;
```

I would not recommend creating a class in that case.

Comment: That's what I did. I used a class to hold all my public static variables, so that I could use them globally as constants. I am a bit confused now, should or should I do it this way?

Comment: Yes that would be a better idea.

Comment: You can create a singleton class as mentioned in my answer and then access the variables using get and set method. This would be a much better approach then using a global variable. :)

Comment: That's what I used before. I used enum to realize the singleton , I usually call it `CNST` and to access a constant `v1` in the enum, I just use `CNST.INST.v1`. However I changed back to use a class with static public constants, so that I could access them as `CNST.v1`. Are you saying the first way is better? why? BTW, all my globals are constants, so setter is not necessary for me.

Comment: just extended the question to [What is the better way of publishing global constants in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169614/what-is-the-better-way-of-publishing-global-constants-in-java)

Comment: In that case I would recommend you to use the old style which is the best in your case. Updated my answer as well!!