# What is the better way of publishing global constants in Java?

Tags: java, enums, singleton, global, final

Which one of these ways of publishing global constants is better? THANKS!!!

`Method 1: final class with public static final fields`

```
public final class CNST{
    private CNST(){}
    public static final String C1;
    public static final String C2;
    static{
       C1="STRING1";
       C2="STRING2";
    }
}
//so I could call C1, C2 like:
//...some code...
//System.out.println(CNST.C1);
//System.out.println(CNST.C2);
```

`Method 2: singleton with enum`

```
public enum CNST{
    INST;
    public final String C1;
    public final String C2;
    CNST{
       C1="STRING1";
       C2="STRING2";
    }
}
//so I could call C1, C2 like:
//...some code...
//System.out.println(CNST.INST.C1);
//System.out.println(CNST.INST.C2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that follows more usual conventions would be like this:

```
public class MyAppConstants {
    public static final String C1 = "STRING1";
    public static final String C2 = "STRING2";
}
```

Then you can refer to it later like this:

```
System.out.println(MyAppConstants.C1);
```

But if I had to pick between the two you give I guess I would choose the first, because the enum is misleading and doesn't help functionally and doesn't make the code clearer.

Comment: Why is using enum to realize singleton misleading?

Comment: This shows how to use enums properly: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html The idea is that an enum is a type with a finite set of possible values, and in your code you pick one of the valid values.  While it is valid Java to put a static final member variable on an enum, you can also do so on a class, so mind as well use that.

Comment: As it points out by [Effective Java](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1376207397&sr=8-1&keywords=effective+java). It's a valid if not preferable way for enum to be adopted to realize singleton. Of course, regular class can't be realized to achieve that, However, to use enum may have many advatanges, as it is point out by this article "[Why Enum Singleton are better in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html)".

Comment: However the question is not whether enum should be adopted to realize singleton. The question is `is singleton a better way to publish global variable or not?` as that is my intention of my question.

Comment: I agree with bgp. Its quite messy and not common to use it with enum. The function of enum is to introduce custom type with finite set of values. This only makes code more messy.

Comment: Also. You do not need static block if you can assign the value to constants in one row. That also makes code messy.

Answer (score 0):

for fans of short'n'sweet code like me, who like to minimize number of characters in code, if you wanna not have the need to pre-pend the constant name with a class name like "MyGlobaConstants", you can create a base activity class, like MyBaseActivity, and extend all your activities from it. As such:

```
public abstract class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

   public static final String SOME_GLOBAL_STRING = "some string";
   public static final int SOME_GLOBAL_INT = 360;
```

Doing this has other benefits as well, such as creating methods that all your activities can use, and is generally a good practice.