# A method has infinite loops

Tags: java, object, for-loop, methods, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a method that uses the `Scanner` class to fill the objects of type `Number` in the matrix according to the number of items in each row. This what I tried to do (something is wrong in it because it looks to contain infinite loops):

```
public void fillMatrix ( ) {
    Number n;
    ArrayList<Number> nums;
    int num1;
    System.out.println("enter number of matrix elements :");
    num1 = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        nums = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            n = new Number();

            System.out.println("enter the numerator of number(" + i + "," + j + "):");
            n.setNumerator(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println("enter the denominator of number(" + i + "," + j + "):");
            n.setDenominator(sc.nextInt());
            nums.add(n);
        }
        matrix.put(i, nums);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the definition of rows and cols ? And what are theirs values ?

Comment: You get num1 from keyboard but you don't use that. You need that for the loops?

Comment: public class Matrix {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);;

    private HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Number>> matrix;
      
    public static int rows, cols;
      
    public Matrix (int rows, int cols ){
          matrix = new HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Number>> ();
          this.rows =rows;
          this.cols=cols;
          
    }
@JFPicard This includes definition of rows and cols

Comment: @Shondeslitch num1 is to get the number of elements in the matrix

Comment: @user233531 but you dont' use that for anything. No matter the value of n1 that you always do the same number of inputs from keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**First**  - you are not making a new scanner object called sc.

**Second** - rows and cols are not defined. Global vars are generally bad practice (See: [What kind of global variable is bad practice in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169280/what-kind-of-global-variable-is-bad-practice-in-java))

Also there are no infinite loops because each for loop ends when `i` reaches rows.

Comment: This is the previous part :
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);;
private HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Number>> matrix;
 public static int rows, cols;
 public Matrix (int rows, int cols ){
 matrix = new HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Number>> ();
          this.rows =rows;
          this.cols=cols;

Comment: @user233531 then don't you close the scanner? It can be the reason why you think you have "infinite loops" when the problem can be that your program is always waiting a new input.

Comment: @user233531 shondeslitch is correct, once you put in all the input it will stop end.

Comment: When I closed the scanner an error appeared, how can I show you the whole class code?